# The keyboard automatically appears when climbing up to the new activity android

Tags: android

I walk into a new activity keyboard automatically appears in the edit texs. How to make teeth appear keyboard then when I click on the edit texs ?

Comment: remove focus from editetext programtically then

Comment: Have you set any property regarding this in your manifest file?

Comment: Yes , I use  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

specify the following `Manifest` entry for your `Activity`:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

For how to hide/show the keyboard refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks whitch help :*